# how to fetch data from Api using statelessWidget

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I'm trying to fetch news data from the api and display the news titles in the home page 
as I know it will not have any Internal changes so I decided to use **StatelessWidget** as well as using **PROVIDER** state management
and now  I'm in trouble with how to call the fetching method with StatelessWidget so I can display titles

this is my fetching data class

```
class NewsRequest with ChangeNotifier{

  static String _url ="https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&from=2019-06-24&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=4d990bdd71324572bca39fe31edc3990";
  static Map<String, String> _apiKey = {"apiKey" : "4d990bdd71324572bca39fe31edc3990"};
  Map <String, dynamic> _data;
  List _articles;
  bool _isFetching = false;
  Map<String, dynamic> result;

bool get isFetching => _isFetching;



Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchData() async{
   _isFetching = true;
try{
  Response response = await get(Uri.encodeFull(_url), headers: _apiKey)
       .timeout(Duration(seconds: 60)); 
       print("STATUSCODE ${response.statusCode}");
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
     _data = json.decode(response.body);
   }
   _isFetching = false;
   notifyListeners();
}on SocketException catch(_){
}on TimeoutException catch(_){
}catch(e){
  e.toString();
  print('CATCH ${e.toString()}');
}
return null;
}

Map<String, dynamic> get getNews => _data;

Map<String , dynamic> getNewsData(){
  if(_data == null){
    print('data is null');
    return null;
  }else{
    _articles = _data['articles'];
  }
print("FIRST ARTICALE IS : ${_articles[0]}");
  return null;
}

}
```

and my Home page call is that

```
body:  newsResponse.isFetching
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : newsResponse.getNewsData()!= null ?
          new ListView.builder(
                itemCount:  newsResponse.getNewsData().length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return new Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: 100,
                          width: 310,
                          ),

                          child: Wrap(children: <Widget>[
                            Text( newsResponse.result['response'][index]['title']),
                          ]),
                        ),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 50,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                             newsResponse.result['response'][index]["urlToImage"]??"",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
          ):
        Container()
```

I need to call **fetchData()** Method in order to run all the staff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start the request directly in the constructor of your `ChangeNotifier`:

```dart
class MyNotifier with ChangeNotifer {
  MyNotifier() {
    // TODO: do an http request
  }
}
```

Comment: what about async .. await ?? the modifier 'async' can't be applied to the body of a constructor.
Try removing the modifier

Comment: Just call your `fetchData` in there.

Answer (score 1):

you should wrap you body with **Consumer** , 
 something like that :

```
Consumer(BuildContext context , NewsRequest model , child) 
{
 return model.isFetching? 
 // put the rest of your code here 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the options are :

1. Load the screen. Get the data. Update the screen.
2. Get the data before the screen loads. Load the screen with pre-fetched data.

The first one is, as you might know, a Stateful thing whereas option #2 is Stateless one.

AFAIK, the best way to do this is :

1. Create a property in the class of Stateless which holds the data to display on the screen. (So, the news info in your case).
2. Fetch the data during splash/main screen loads. And call the screen by passing the data to it.

Sample implementation :
In one of my app, I've a list to be fetched from the web API and display in the mobile app. I divided the overall functionality in two files. The main file/class for the list one is Stateless.

In the header file, I get the data as below :

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
      _requestLeaveList();
    }
```

This sets a variable called _leaveList.

Now, I call the screen as below :

```
Expanded(
   child: LeaveListView(leaves: _listLeaves,),
)
```

And the LeaveListView is Stateless.